# Forcing client certificate use in Airflow SSL

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, airflow

I have an Apache Airflow deployment with SSL configured through

```
    web_server_ssl_cert: <path to crt file>
    web_server_ssl_key: <path to key file>
    web_server_port: 8443
    base_url: https://<IP address>:8443
```

However, when I run the command:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect <IP address>:8443
```

I can see the server cert details but no client cert:

```
No client certificate CA names sent
```

How do I ensure that user client certificate is used in my Airflow deployment?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two configuration variables. Here are the requirements for SSL using CeleryExecutor:

```
[celery]
ssl_active = True
ssl_key = <path to key>
ssl_cert = <path to cert>
ssl_cacert = <path to cacert>
```

From: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/security.html?highlight=celery#ssl